# Print composer will not show maps when reopened

Tags: qgis, print-composer, printing

I completed a print composer project, locked layer and layer style files and locked the map, then saved the print composer, then saved the complete project.  I closed QGIS and when I opened the project again, the saved print composer didn't display the map. All other items, legend labels etc are saved and displayed.

I tried to refresh render/ rectangle/ cache and it didn't work. I had to make the map again.

Comment: Have you unlocked the map-element and then refreshed it? Also, you could export your map as a PDF, why is this not an option?

Comment: Hmm, I just tried to open a closed project, I could not reproduce the error you mentioned, could it be depend on what type of layers you have loaded?